# How to extract JSON object in a Google Apps Script web app?

Tags: arrays, json, google-apps-script, web-applications

Can someone point out why this function would not work?

```
 function doPost(e) {
        var contents = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
        var data = JSON.stringify(contents,null,4);
        var x = data["inboundSMSMessageList"];
        var y= x.inboundSMSMessage[0].senderAddress;
        GmailApp.sendEmail("sample.email@gmail.com", "test5", y); 
        }
```

It takes an event listener, e, parses its contents and then stringily the contents using JSON.parse() and JSON.stringify() respectively. This is a sample stringified data:

```
var data = {
    "inboundSMSMessageList": {
        "inboundSMSMessage": [
            {
                "dateTime": "Sun Jan 03 2021 01:25:03 GMT+0000 (UTC)",
                "destinationAddress": "tel:21585789",
                "messageId": "5ff11cef73cf74588ab2a735",
                "message": "Yes",
                "resourceURL": null,
                "senderAddress": "tel:+63917xxxxx"
            }
        ],
        "numberOfMessagesInThisBatch": 1,
        "resourceURL": null,
        "totalNumberOfPendingMessages": 0
    }
}
```

The script seems to fail on the second to the last line (var y); but when I run it on the sample data, I'm able to access the key and value pair Im targeting- which is the sender address (it sends "tel:+63917xxxxx: to my email). Anybody has an idea why it's failing when it's ran as a web app?

Answer (score 1):

I thought that in your script, `var contents = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);` can be used as the parsed object. I thought that the reason of your error is due to that the object is converted to the string by `var data = JSON.stringify(contents,null,4)`. So how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var contents = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
var data = JSON.stringify(contents,null,4);
```

#### To:

```
var data = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
```

- In this modification, `y` is `tel:+63917xxxxx`.

#### Note:

- When you modified the script of Web Apps, please redeploy the Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to the Web Apps. Please be careful this.

Answer (score 0):

Use template literals before parsing your json request.

`` const body = JSON.parse(`${e.postData.contents}`) ``

e.postData.contents return a json without string wrapped on whole json request. It will return something like this `{"sheetName":"TEST"}` and returning a `Uncaught SyntaxError: "[object Object]" is not valid JSON` when you try to parse it without string wrapped.